# Cant install ML.NET on MAC OS (DotnetTool not supported by project)

Tags: c#, rider, ml.net

I'm trying to install `mlnet 0.15.1` on Mac OS `10.14.6` (Mojave) using the `Rider` and `.Net Framework v4.7.2`, but I am still getting error message saying that `DotnetTool` is not supported by the project.

What does it mean?

Full log using .NetCore:

```
Credential provider preference: Rider
Start restoring packages for solution
@ Restoring packages in solution horczechTryingStuff started
@   RestorePackagesConfig: Start
@   There are no packages in solution
@   RestorePackagesConfig: Finish
@   RestorePackageReferences: Start
@   Restoring NuGet packages for integrated projects: start
@   RestoreEngine = Embedded
Running non-parallel restore.
Reading project file /Users/horczech/Csharp/Playground/horczechTryingStuff/horczechTryingStuff/horczechTryingStuff.csproj.
Persisting no-op dg to /Users/horczech/Csharp/Playground/horczechTryingStuff/horczechTryingStuff/obj/horczechTryingStuff.csproj.nuget.dgspec.json
Restoring packages for /Users/horczech/Csharp/Playground/horczechTryingStuff/horczechTryingStuff/horczechTryingStuff.csproj...
Restoring packages for .NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1...
Resolving conflicts for .NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1...
Checking compatibility of packages on .NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1.
All packages and projects are compatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1.
Committing restore...
Generating MSBuild file /Users/horczech/Csharp/Playground/horczechTryingStuff/horczechTryingStuff/obj/horczechTryingStuff.csproj.nuget.g.props.
Generating MSBuild file /Users/horczech/Csharp/Playground/horczechTryingStuff/horczechTryingStuff/obj/horczechTryingStuff.csproj.nuget.g.targets.
Writing assets file to disk. Path: /Users/horczech/Csharp/Playground/horczechTryingStuff/horczechTryingStuff/obj/project.assets.json
Writing cache file to disk. Path: /Users/horczech/Csharp/Playground/horczechTryingStuff/horczechTryingStuff/obj/horczechTryingStuff.csproj.nuget.cache
Restore completed in 355.29 ms for /Users/horczech/Csharp/Playground/horczechTryingStuff/horczechTryingStuff/horczechTryingStuff.csproj.
@   Restoring NuGet packages for integrated projects: finish
@   RestorePackageReferences: Finish
@   Restore result: Affected projects: horczechTryingStuff; Affected packages folders: /Users/horczech/.nuget/packages
@ Restoring packages in solution horczechTryingStuff finished (0.422 sec)
Finish restoring packages for solution
@ Installing mlnet in horczechTryingStuff started
Running non-parallel restore.
Reading project file /Users/horczech/Csharp/Playground/horczechTryingStuff/horczechTryingStuff/horczechTryingStuff.csproj.
Persisting no-op dg to /Users/horczech/Csharp/Playground/horczechTryingStuff/horczechTryingStuff/obj/horczechTryingStuff.csproj.nuget.dgspec.json
Restoring packages for /Users/horczech/Csharp/Playground/horczechTryingStuff/horczechTryingStuff/horczechTryingStuff.csproj...
Restoring packages for .NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1...
Resolving conflicts for .NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1...
Checking compatibility of packages on .NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1.
Package mlnet 0.15.1 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package mlnet 0.15.1 supports: netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1) / any
Invalid project-package combination for mlnet 0.15.1. DotnetToolReference project style can only contain references of the DotnetTool type 
Package 'mlnet 0.15.1' has a package type 'DotnetTool' that is not supported by project '/Users/horczech/Csharp/Playground/horczechTryingStuff/horczechTryingStuff/horczechTryingStuff.csproj'.
NuGet.Packaging.Core.PackagingException: Package 'mlnet 0.15.1' has a package type 'DotnetTool' that is not supported by project '/Users/horczech/Csharp/Playground/horczechTryingStuff/horczechTryingStuff/horczechTryingStuff.csproj'.
  at JetBrains.ProjectModel.NuGet.Operations.NuGetPatchedInstallationCompatibility.EnsurePackageCompatibility (NuGet.ProjectManagement.NuGetProject nuGetProject, NuGet.Packaging.Core.PackageIdentity packageIdentity, NuGet.Packaging.NuspecReader nuspecReader) [0x000de] in <9e74cc1509e64004872b83a95141bc23>:0 
  at JetBrains.ProjectModel.NuGet.Operations.NuGetPatchedInstallationCompatibility.EnsurePackageCompatibility (NuGet.ProjectManagement.NuGetProject nuGetProject, NuGet.Common.INuGetPathContext pathContext, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] nuGetProjectActions, NuGet.Commands.RestoreResult restoreResult) [0x00140] in <9e74cc1509e64004872b83a95141bc23>:0 
  at NuGet.PackageManagement.NuGetPackageManager.PreviewBuildIntegratedProjectActionsAsync (NuGet.ProjectManagement.Projects.BuildIntegratedNuGetProject buildIntegratedProject, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] nuGetProjectActions, NuGet.ProjectManagement.INuGetProjectContext nuGetProjectContext, System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x00827] in <71c0d022d372446180b5b43080e43ac4>:0 
  at NuGet.PackageManagement.NuGetPackageManager.PreviewInstallPackageAsync (NuGet.ProjectManagement.NuGetProject nuGetProject, NuGet.Packaging.Core.PackageIdentity packageIdentity, NuGet.PackageManagement.ResolutionContext resolutionContext, NuGet.ProjectManagement.INuGetProjectContext nuGetProjectContext, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] primarySources, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] secondarySources, System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x001d7] in <71c0d022d372446180b5b43080e43ac4>:0 
  at NuGet.PackageManagement.NuGetPackageManager.InstallPackageAsync (NuGet.ProjectManagement.NuGetProject nuGetProject, NuGet.Packaging.Core.PackageIdentity packageIdentity, NuGet.PackageManagement.ResolutionContext resolutionContext, NuGet.ProjectManagement.INuGetProjectContext nuGetProjectContext, NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.PackageDownloadContext downloadContext, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] primarySources, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] secondarySources, System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x0009b] in <71c0d022d372446180b5b43080e43ac4>:0 
  at NuGet.PackageManagement.NuGetPackageManager.InstallPackageAsync (NuGet.ProjectManagement.NuGetProject nuGetProject, NuGet.Packaging.Core.PackageIdentity packageIdentity, NuGet.PackageManagement.ResolutionContext resolutionContext, NuGet.ProjectManagement.INuGetProjectContext nuGetProjectContext, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] primarySources, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] secondarySources, System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x000d3] in <71c0d022d372446180b5b43080e43ac4>:0 
  at JetBrains.ProjectModel.NuGet.Operations.NuGetInstallOperation+<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<InstallAsync>b__0 (NuGet.ProjectManagement.NuGetProject nuGetProject, System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x000a5] in <9e74cc1509e64004872b83a95141bc23>:0 
  at JetBrains.ProjectModel.NuGet.Operations.NuGetInstallOperation.InstallInternal (JetBrains.ProjectModel.IProject project, System.String packageId, System.String packgeUserStr, JetBrains.ProjectModel.NuGet.Configs.NuGetFeedContext feedContext, System.Int32 nestedLevel, JetBrains.ProjectModel.NuGet.Logging.NuGetNotificationMode mode, JetBrains.ProjectModel.NuGet.Operations.NuGetOperationReporter reporter, System.Func`3[T1,T2,TResult] nativeInstall) [0x003e6] in <9e74cc1509e64004872b83a95141bc23>:0 

@ Installing mlnet in horczechTryingStuff finished (0.281 sec)
[Notification][Install] Install failed (project: horczechTryingStuff, package: mlnet v0.15.1)
Package 'mlnet 0.15.1' has a package type 'DotnetTool' that is not supported by project '/Users/horczech/Csharp/Playground/horczechTryingStuff/horczechTryingStuff/horczechTryingStuff.csproj'.
```

Full log using .NetFramework:

```
Credential provider preference: Rider
@ Installing mlnet in horczechIsGettingPissed started
Attempting to gather dependency information for package 'mlnet.0.15.1' with respect to project '/Users/horczech/Csharp/Playground/horczechIsGettingPissed/horczechIsGettingPissed', targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2'
Gathering dependency information took 11.67 ms
Attempting to resolve dependencies for package 'mlnet.0.15.1' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
Resolving dependency information took 0 ms
Resolving actions to install package 'mlnet.0.15.1'
Resolved actions to install package 'mlnet.0.15.1'
Retrieving package 'mlnet 0.15.1' from 'nuget.org'.
Install failed. Rolling back...
Package 'mlnet.0.15.1' does not exist in project 'horczechIsGettingPissed'
Package 'mlnet.0.15.1' does not exist in folder '/Users/horczech/Csharp/Playground/horczechIsGettingPissed/packages'
Executing nuget actions took 1.29 sec
Package 'mlnet 0.15.1' has a package type 'DotnetTool' that is not supported by project '/Users/horczech/Csharp/Playground/horczechIsGettingPissed/horczechIsGettingPissed'.
NuGet.Packaging.Core.PackagingException: Package 'mlnet 0.15.1' has a package type 'DotnetTool' that is not supported by project '/Users/horczech/Csharp/Playground/horczechIsGettingPissed/horczechIsGettingPissed'.
  at JetBrains.ProjectModel.NuGet.Operations.NuGetPatchedInstallationCompatibility.EnsurePackageCompatibility (NuGet.ProjectManagement.NuGetProject nuGetProject, NuGet.Packaging.Core.PackageIdentity packageIdentity, NuGet.Packaging.NuspecReader nuspecReader) [0x000de] in <9e74cc1509e64004872b83a95141bc23>:0 
  at JetBrains.ProjectModel.NuGet.Operations.NuGetPatchedInstallationCompatibility.EnsurePackageCompatibilityAsync (NuGet.ProjectManagement.NuGetProject nuGetProject, NuGet.Packaging.Core.PackageIdentity packageIdentity, NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.DownloadResourceResult resourceResult, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x000fb] in <9e74cc1509e64004872b83a95141bc23>:0 
  at NuGet.PackageManagement.NuGetPackageManager.ExecuteInstallAsync (NuGet.ProjectManagement.NuGetProject nuGetProject, NuGet.Packaging.Core.PackageIdentity packageIdentity, NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.DownloadResourceResult resourceResult, System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[T] packageWithDirectoriesToBeDeleted, NuGet.ProjectManagement.INuGetProjectContext nuGetProjectContext, System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x00089] in <71c0d022d372446180b5b43080e43ac4>:0 
  at NuGet.PackageManagement.NuGetPackageManager.ExecuteNuGetProjectActionsAsync (NuGet.ProjectManagement.NuGetProject nuGetProject, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] nuGetProjectActions, NuGet.ProjectManagement.INuGetProjectContext nuGetProjectContext, NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.PackageDownloadContext downloadContext, System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x00924] in <71c0d022d372446180b5b43080e43ac4>:0 
  at NuGet.PackageManagement.NuGetPackageManager.ExecuteNuGetProjectActionsAsync (NuGet.ProjectManagement.NuGetProject nuGetProject, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] nuGetProjectActions, NuGet.ProjectManagement.INuGetProjectContext nuGetProjectContext, NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.PackageDownloadContext downloadContext, System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x00aa3] in <71c0d022d372446180b5b43080e43ac4>:0 
  at NuGet.PackageManagement.NuGetPackageManager.ExecuteNuGetProjectActionsAsync (NuGet.ProjectManagement.NuGetProject nuGetProject, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] nuGetProjectActions, NuGet.ProjectManagement.INuGetProjectContext nuGetProjectContext, NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.PackageDownloadContext downloadContext, System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x011a0] in <71c0d022d372446180b5b43080e43ac4>:0 
  at NuGet.PackageManagement.NuGetPackageManager.InstallPackageAsync (NuGet.ProjectManagement.NuGetProject nuGetProject, NuGet.Packaging.Core.PackageIdentity packageIdentity, NuGet.PackageManagement.ResolutionContext resolutionContext, NuGet.ProjectManagement.INuGetProjectContext nuGetProjectContext, NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.PackageDownloadContext downloadContext, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] primarySources, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] secondarySources, System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x00121] in <71c0d022d372446180b5b43080e43ac4>:0 
  at NuGet.PackageManagement.NuGetPackageManager.InstallPackageAsync (NuGet.ProjectManagement.NuGetProject nuGetProject, NuGet.Packaging.Core.PackageIdentity packageIdentity, NuGet.PackageManagement.ResolutionContext resolutionContext, NuGet.ProjectManagement.INuGetProjectContext nuGetProjectContext, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] primarySources, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] secondarySources, System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x000d3] in <71c0d022d372446180b5b43080e43ac4>:0 
  at JetBrains.ProjectModel.NuGet.Operations.NuGetInstallOperation+<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<InstallAsync>b__0 (NuGet.ProjectManagement.NuGetProject nuGetProject, System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x000a5] in <9e74cc1509e64004872b83a95141bc23>:0 
  at JetBrains.ProjectModel.NuGet.Operations.NuGetInstallOperation.InstallInternal (JetBrains.ProjectModel.IProject project, System.String packageId, System.String packgeUserStr, JetBrains.ProjectModel.NuGet.Configs.NuGetFeedContext feedContext, System.Int32 nestedLevel, JetBrains.ProjectModel.NuGet.Logging.NuGetNotificationMode mode, JetBrains.ProjectModel.NuGet.Operations.NuGetOperationReporter reporter, System.Func`3[T1,T2,TResult] nativeInstall) [0x003e6] in <9e74cc1509e64004872b83a95141bc23>:0 

@ Installing mlnet in horczechIsGettingPissed finished (1.362 sec)
[Notification][Install] Install failed (project: horczechIsGettingPissed, package: mlnet v0.15.1)
Package 'mlnet 0.15.1' has a package type 'DotnetTool' that is not supported by project '/Users/horczech/Csharp/Playground/horczechIsGettingPissed/horczechIsGettingPissed'.
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with ML.NET. The error complains that `horczechIsGettingPissed` is a .NET Framework project, not .NET Core. You can't even build such a project on MacOS in the first place.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos so you are saying that there is no way how to use ML.NET on mac os?

Comment: Quite the opposite. I'm saying you created the wrong project type. Create a .NET Core project instead and add them. It's impossible to build a .NET Old project in MacOS in the first place. I'm not sure you can add .NET Core *local* tools to a .NET Old project even on Windows either. You can add them as global tools

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Actually I tried .NetCore project before and I got  this error (full log added to original question) 

Package mlnet 0.15.1 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package mlnet 0.15.1 supports: netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos but the real problem was that I was trying to install mlnet which is CLI. I have to install nuget package Microsoft.ML

Comment: Ask for *that* error then. Trying with a completely incompatible project type won't help. .NET Core works just fine on Mac OS.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos as I said in the previous comment. mlnet is CLI, what I really wanted was a package called Microsoft.ML.

Comment: You'll have to provide enough information for people to reproduce the problem. What kind of project did you create? How did you add the package? Posting a log doesn't show what you did in the UI. Can you reproduce the same issue if you use the command line? Eg `dotnet new console` and then `dotnet tool install --global MLNet --version 0.15.1` ?

Comment: it's a tool, not "CLI" and you didn't actually post how you tried to add it. The tool is installed globally, while you posted a log of a project trying to restore packages. *Have* you tried `dotnet tool install -g mlnet` ? Did you follow the instructions [here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/learn/ml-dotnet/get-started-tutorial/install) ?